# How can I turn ClusterRouterPool from C# to HOCON configuration?

Tags: c#, mono, akka.net, akka.net-cluster

I'm learning akka.net and potentially will use it to replace part of our traditional message driven app.

Basically I'm trying to have **X number of nodes joined to a cluster**. It's **peer to peer** type, and I might run X number of actors (same actor) on a node.

If I have 10 jobs (say SendEmailActor), ideally, I would like each of the 10 jobs be executed on different nodes (spread the load evenly).

I have an extremely simple console app to demonstrate.

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using Akka;
using Akka.Actor;
using Akka.Cluster;
using Akka.Cluster.Routing;
using Akka.Configuration;
using Akka.Configuration.Hocon;
using Akka.Routing;

namespace Console1
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Is this the seed node? (Y/n): ");

            var port = Console.ReadLine().ToLowerInvariant() == "y" ? 9999 : 0;

            var section = (AkkaConfigurationSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("akka");

            var config =
                ConfigurationFactory.ParseString("akka.remote.helios.tcp.port=" + port)
                    .WithFallback(section.AkkaConfig);

            var cluster = ActorSystem.Create("MyCluster", config);

            var worker = cluster.ActorOf(Props.Create<Worker>().WithRouter(
                                 new ClusterRouterPool(
                                     new RoundRobinPool(10),
                                     new ClusterRouterPoolSettings(30, true, 5))), "worker");

            while (true)
            {
                Console.Read();
                var i = DateTime.Now.Millisecond;
                Console.WriteLine("Announce: {0}", i);
                worker.Tell(i);

            }
        }
    }

    public class Worker : UntypedActor
    {
        protected override void OnReceive(object message)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(new Random().Next(1000, 2000));
            Console.WriteLine("WORKER ({0}) [{1}:{2}]", message, Context.Self.Path, Cluster.Get(Context.System).SelfUniqueAddress.Address.Port);
        }
    }
}
```

And my app.config looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="akka" type="Akka.Configuration.Hocon.AkkaConfigurationSection, Akka" />
    </configSections>
    <akka>
    <hocon>
        <![CDATA[
            akka {
                actor {
                    provider = "Akka.Cluster.ClusterActorRefProvider, Akka.Cluster"
                }

                remote {
                    helios.tcp {
                        hostname = "127.0.0.1"
                        port = 0
                    }
                }            

                cluster {
                    seed-nodes = ["akka.tcp://MyCluster@127.0.0.1:9999"]
                }
            }
        ]]>
    </hocon>
    </akka>
</configuration>
```

I want to use HOCON and setup akka.actor.deployment, and I couldn't get it to work. I don't quite understand the **routees.paths**, and its relationship with the the **actor.deployment/worker** and how will routees.paths map to the actors created in C#.

```
actor {
    provider = "Akka.Cluster.ClusterActorRefProvider, Akka.Cluster"
    deployment {
        /worker {
            router = roundrobin-pool
            routees.paths = ["/worker"] # what's this?
            cluster {
                    enabled = on
                    max-nr-of-instances-per-node = 1
                    allow-local-routees = on
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Another question: with aka.net.cluster is it possible to "mirror" the nodes to provide redundancy? Or GuaranteedDeliveryActor (I think it's renamed to AtLeastOnceDelivery) is the way to go?

Comment: You are mixing Group and Pool configuration settings, see http://getakka.net/docs/working-with-actors/Routers#roundrobin  .. `paths` are for group routers while you are trying to create a pool router

Comment: @RogerAlsing, thanks. I got it working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @RogerAlsing.

The C# line looks like this

`var worker = cluster.ActorOf(Props.Create(() => new Worker()).WithRouter(FromConfig.Instance), "worker");`

and the config looks like

```
akka {
        actor {
            provider = "Akka.Cluster.ClusterActorRefProvider, Akka.Cluster"
            deployment {
                /worker {
                    router = round-robin-pool #broadcast-pool also works
                    nr-of-instances = 10
                    cluster {
                            enabled = on
                            max-nr-of-instances-per-node = 2
                            allow-local-routees = on
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        remote {
            helios.tcp {
                hostname = "127.0.0.1"
                port = 0
            }
        }            

        cluster {
            seed-nodes = ["akka.tcp://MyCluster@127.0.0.1:9999"]
        }
    }
```